# Develop a graphical interface for Python applications

Tags: python, django, user-interface, tkinter

I am developing a python application.
This application generates as a final result a table of type .xlsx

To reach the final table I used Anaconda's jupyter.

I would like to create a graphical interface for the python application. However, I have some theoretical doubts on the subject:

Since, I would like to enter the table and show the statistical results to the user (according to filters applied by the users). What would be the most appropriate approach?

```
      Option A) Use an interpreter, such as TkInter? Are these interpreters capable of
                generating an executable? Is it able to receive a data entry table?

      Option B) Use a web framework, such as Django. Does this framwork host the built page?
                 It is capable of receiving a data entry table.
```

I am open to more options. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you use Tkinter. You can use pyinstaller to convert the py file to exe

Comment: Also, I have seen people make tables just like you ar e trying with tkinter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have one more question: the code developed in the Anaconda environment is of the ipynb type and this generates an xlsx type file. You know what the development process would be: type 1) I send the data table as input and create fields so that the user can filter their desired characteristics.
type 2) Convert my code (ipynb) to an executable?

Comment: I am not an expert on what you are trying to do! I have just started myself, and I simply suggested this technique which I am using, and other people are as well.

Comment: Ok. Thank you  for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

tk is better for a distributed desktop application. It can be packaged and distrubuted.

Another option is a cool package called Eel, kinda like electron for python. You can build desktop apps using html, css, js, and most of all python: https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel